# Replace parts of string using package stringi (regex)

Tags: regex, r, string, stringi

I have some string

```
string <- "abbccc"
```

I want to replace the chains of the same letter to just one letter and number of occurance of this letter. So I want to have something like this:
`"ab2c3"`

I use `stringi` package to do this, but it doesn't work exactly like I want. Let's say I already have vector with parts for replacement:

```
vector <- c("b2", "c3")
stri_replace_all_regex(string, "([a-z])\\1{1,8}", vector)
```

The output:

```
[1] "ab2b2" "ac3c3"
```

The output I want: `[1] "ab2c3"`

I also tried this way

```
stri_replace_all_regex(string, "([a-z])\\1{1,8}", vector, vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

but i get error

```
Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, "([a-z])\\1{1,8}", vector, vectorize_all = FALSE) : 
  vector length not consistent with other arguments
```

Comment: What is the expected output for `string <- 'bbaccc'` Is it `'b2ac3'`

Comment: It's `"b2ac3"`. Other examples `"good" --> "go2d"`, `"uffff" --> "uf4"`. I know how to create a vector with "new" parts instead of  old ones but I don't know how to replace it properly.

Comment: Sorry, you're ok. The type of quotes doesn't matter of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not regex but a`strsplit` and `rle` with some `paste` magic:

```
string <- c("abbccc", "bbaccc", "uffff", "aaabccccddd")

sapply(lapply(strsplit(string, ""), rle), function(x) {
    paste(x[[2]], ifelse(x[[1]] == 1, "", x[[1]]), sep="", collapse="")
})

## [1] "ab2c3"   "b2ac3"   "uf4"     "a3bc4d3"
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a `stringi` solution and not a `regex` either, but you can do it by splitting the string and using `rle`:

```
    string <- "abbccc"
    res<-paste(collapse="",do.call(paste0,rle(strsplit(string,"",fixed=TRUE)[[1]])[2:1]))
    gsub("1","",res)
    #[1] "ab2c3"
```